# "=>" causes bad autoindentation in code snippets

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, stack-snippets

Paste this JS code in the stack snippet editor:

```
(function() {
  console.log(foo + "=>");
})();
```

Select it all with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to autoindent. The code becomes

```
(function() {
  console.log(foo + "=>");
              })();
```

It works properly when using the equivalent `"=\>"`. This makes me wonder if the autoindent uses some naive regex in order to detect arrow functions, but [one can't parse JS with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630).

Comment: I hate that Shift+Tab causes auto-indent instead of reducing the indent level by one. I've grown used to certain shortcuts doing certain things and the snippet editor doesn't follow that. I always edit my code in my preferred editor before pasting into the snipped editor for this exact reason.

Comment: @SeinopSys But autoindent is so handy when a newbie posts an horrendously formatted question.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a useful feature, but they could have bound it to a shortcut that does not already have a widely known function, or they could have made it a button on the side.

Comment: Looks like the hashrocket has achieved lift-off!

Comment: Isn't it already Ctrl-k anyway?

Comment: Note that the `Tidy` button doesn’t cause this problem.

Comment: @JF Yep, but the Tidy button does not autoindent.

Comment: @Oriol Try dedenting the code snippet provided, then click “Tidy.”

Comment: @JF Ah, you are right. But it does something weird, if you have a well indented code and add the same number of spaces before each line, then they are not removed.

Comment: I'm looking. we use code mirror there, will have to dig into how it handles shortcuts... since it doesn't do anything when selecting multiple lines and pressing `tab` (one would expect it to intend by a level), I guess preventing it from handling `shift+tab` is also an option

Answer (score 3):

Build rev `2017.2.16.25125` has the latests code mirror release, I've also tweaked the key bindings a bit:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> adds indentation to the lines in the current selection, or jumps to the next tab stop (adding either 1 or 2 spaces) if nothing is selected. Previously it just added 2 spaces.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> removes an indentation level, from the lines in the current selection, since this is how most developers expect it to behave.

Previously it was using the `CodeMirror.commands.indentAuto` which was buggy in the old codemirror release.

I've also remapped that command to the tidy function for the given editor, so if anybody wants to remap it back in a user script (e.g. `CodeMirror.keyMaps.default['Shift-Tab'] = 'indentAuto'`).

Comment: you're right, I forgot to pull in the latest mode files when updating codemirror

Comment: Is there a new shortcut to auto-indent the code or does this functionnality is gone?

Comment: @Veve it's gone, but if you really want it, the command is still there, and works consistently with the tidy link now

Comment: Didn't know it existed before. I think we loose a little bit with this function not directly accessible anymore outside the Snippet editor. (I won't open it just for this)

Comment: it was never accessible outside the snippet editor

Comment: OK, I though it was also accessible directly in the normal editor.