# Stack snippet Auto indentation not work anymore

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

I just noticed that the Auto indentation (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>) does not indent the code anymore in the stack snippet but instead reduce the indent level by one, example to make a fast test :

```html
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea
<ul>
<li>Black tea</li>
<li>Green tea</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Related (not duplicate): ["=>" causes bad autoindentation in code snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339779/causes-bad-autoindentation-in-code-snippets)

Comment: I've linked this question because it explain why the Shift+Tab isn't linked to auto-indent anymore.

Answer (score -1):

From [m0sa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343971/4074148):

> <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> removes an indentation level, from the
>   lines in the current selection, since this is how most developers
>   expect it to behave.
>
> Previously it was using the `CodeMirror.commands.indentAuto` which was
>   buggy in the old codemirror release.
>
> I've also remapped that command to the tidy function for the given
>   editor, so if anybody wants to remap it back in a user script (e.g.
>   `CodeMirror.keyMaps.default['Shift-Tab'] = 'indentAuto'`).

And from [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339779/causes-bad-autoindentation-in-code-snippets#comment449005_343971):

> if you really want it, the command is still there, and works
>   consistently with the tidy link now

The `Tidy` link in question corresponds to the `Tidy` button present at the upper left corner of the Snippet editor.